# Flutter use only one finger print registered in mobile

Tags: android, ios, flutter, fingerprint, face-id

Flutter ,Can constrain login with only one mobile fingerprint ?
I used local-auth but application accept all mobile fingerprint was registered

Comment: On Android, no. That is not something offered by the OS, assuming that you are referring to the OS-supplied fingerprint support.

Comment: iOS again, no.  Local Authentication just returns true/false if an authentication was successful. There is no way to specify which enrolled finger can be used.  This wouldn't be a good idea anyway; If someone injures a finger they may well want to use an alternate finger.  On iOS you can store a value in the keychain, protected by touchId/FaceId and set it so that the value is removed if the biometric database is modified (additional finger enrolled, for example), but this isn't exactly what you are asking for